# Выбор поддерживаемого браузером формата изображения

Tags: .htaccess, изображения, формат

Как c помощью .htaccess подгружать картинки в формате webp, а в тех случаях, когда такой формат не поддерживается браузером, подгружать обычную png или jpg?

Comment: А при чём тут nginx?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно решение именно для сервера nginx. Не редко я нахожу пример решения этой задачи для Apache.

Comment: nginx и htaccess в одном предложении не сочетаются никак

Comment: Так что выберите что-то одно

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что .htaccess и nginx никак не связаны??

Comment: Никак. htaccess это только apache